# Ruby: How to find out if a character is a letter or a digit?

Tags: ruby, string, character, digits

I just started tinkering with Ruby earlier this week and I've run into something that I don't quite know how to code. I'm converting a scanner that was written in Java into Ruby for a class assignment, and I've gotten down to this section:

```
if (Character.isLetter(lookAhead))
{      
    return id();
}

if (Character.isDigit(lookAhead))
{
    return number();
}
```

`lookAhead` is a single character picked out of the string (moving by one space each time it loops through) and these two methods determine if it is a character or a digit, returning the appropriate token type. I haven't been able to figure out a Ruby equivalent to `Character.isLetter()` and `Character.isDigit()`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use a regular expression that matches letters & digits:

```
def letter?(lookAhead)
  lookAhead.match?(/[[:alpha:]]/)
end

def numeric?(lookAhead)
  lookAhead.match?(/[[:digit:]]/)
end
```

These are called POSIX bracket expressions, and the advantage of them is that unicode characters under the given category will match. For example:

```
'ñ'.match?(/[A-Za-z]/)     #=> false
'ñ'.match?(/\w/)           #=> false
'ñ'.match?(/[[:alpha:]]/)  #=> true
```

You can read more in [Ruby’s docs for regular expressions](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html).

Comment: `lookAhead =~ /[[:alnum:]]/` if you just want to check whether the char is alphanumeric without needing to know which.

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way would be to use a Regular Expression:

```
def numeric?(lookAhead)
  lookAhead =~ /[0-9]/
end

def letter?(lookAhead)
  lookAhead =~ /[A-Za-z]/
end
```

Comment: This is broken: `letter?('Ä') # => false`.

Comment: `/[[:digit:]]/` is better than `/[0-9]/` & `/[[:alpha:]]/` is better than `/[A-Za-z]/`. This will match unicode digits/letters.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Correct, I wasn't thinking about Unicode.  My primary point was that Regex was the way to go, and your answer is the more accurate one for letters.  I'm not sure if there exists a Unicode digit however, in which case the answers are identical for digits.

Comment: @PinnyM There are plenty of [non-ASCII digit characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerals_in_Unicode).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Gosh, I never knew about this - thanks for the link!

Answer (score 7):

Regular expression is an overkill here, it's much more expensive in terms of performance. If you just need a check is character a digit or not there is a simpler way:

```rb
def is_digit?(s)
  code = s.ord
  # 48 is ASCII code of 0
  # 57 is ASCII code of 9
  48 <= code && code <= 57
end

is_digit?("2")
=> true

is_digit?("0")
=> true

is_digit?("9")
=> true

is_digit?("/")
=> false

is_digit?("d")
=> false
```

Comment: This is good (for ASCII digits), but will also return true for strings that just _start_ with a digit, e.g. `'1 is the loneliest number'.ord => 49`.