# Regex absolute begginer: filter alphanumeric

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm playing [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/not-very-secure/train/ruby) in Ruby and I'm stuck on a Kata. The goal is to validate if a user input string is alphanumeric. (yes, this is quite advanced Regex)

The instructions:

```
At least one character ("" is not valid)
Allowed characters are uppercase / lowercase latin letters and digits from 0 to 9
No whitespaces/underscore
```

What I've tried :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
^(?! !)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
^((?! !)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

It passes all the test except one, here's the error message:

```
Value is not what was expected
```

I though the Regex I'm using would satisfy all the conditions, what am I missing ?

---

**SOLUTION:** `\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z` (and better Ruby :^) )

- `$`  => end of a **line**
- `\z` => end of a **string**

(same for beginning: `^` (line) and `\A` (string), but wasn't needed for the test)

Favourite answer from another player:

```
/\A[A-z\d]+\z/
```

Comment: Perhaps try `\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\z`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Same error sadly... It works well with test strings on regex101 but it doesnt pass the test

Comment: Can you add the data from your test to the question?

Comment: I've just added few more tests, they all pass except the last one (I don't know what the test is tho)

Comment: This should work `string.match /\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\z/`

Comment: Well, `\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z` should work

Comment: Oh my god I'm so noob... Yes those regex works, thanks. `\z` works but `$`, I didnt know the subtlety (I still don't really). 

The problem was mainly my ruby syntax tho, I was running:
`print !!(string.match /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/)`
because at some point, it was only working with the `print`. 
I'm ashamed and grateful at the same time ^^ Thanks !

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267058/regex-to-check-alphanumeric-string-in-ruby
the solution doesn't have to involve a regex ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @prettycoder lol ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ

Comment: @prettycoder, the right forearm needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe, we would start with an expression similar to:

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

and test to see if it might cover our desired rules.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T39cu9/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Test

```
re = /^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$/m
str = ' 
ab
c
def
abc*
def^
'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

Comment: That's the same as `r = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/`, but try this `"a1\n@".match?(r) #=> true`. Can you spot the problem?

Comment: It doesn't works, but thank you a lot because I didn't knew we could pass a block to `scan`. It's gonna help me a lot to do some test ! Also I don't really get the goal of `(?=.)`, could you briefly explain ?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The problem comes from `$` which means _"end of the line"_ ? When it meets `\n` it stops scanning and return `true` because `a1` is valid and `@` is ignored ? 
So I guess this is why we should use `\z` right ?

Comment: @Emma thanks for the advises ! I'll keep experimenting, it looks like there's sooo much to know about regular expressions ! Hopefully regex101 helps a lot
Have a great day/evening :)

Comment: @Sumak, yes, here we need to use the string anchors `\A` and `\z`. When it is known that the string contains no newline characters you can use either those anchors of the line anchors `^` and `$`, but it's best to use the set of anchors that reflects your intent, in part so that you don't confuse readers. If I see line anchors where string anchors are intended I need to waste time examining the code to ensure the the coder did not have a reason for avoiding the use of string anchors. Also, in this case an error may be introduced if in future strings may contain newline characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
str !~ /[^A-Za-z\d]/
```

The string contains alphanumeric characters only if and only if it does *not* contain a character other than an alphnumeric character.